# How to trigger change on dynamically created element

Tags: firefox, checkbox, firefox-developer-tools

There is an issue occurring when selecting the checkbox. The checkbox is not working properly for Firefox ESR 102. But it is working fine with Firefox ESR 68.4.2 version as well as the google chrome.

This method doesn't call when using Firefox ESR 102 that the issue. Any way to write this method to be compatible with both Firefox versions.

```
$(document).on('change', '#specialNote', function (e) {
    var value = "N";
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        value = "Y";
    }
    productEvent.updateSpecialNote($('#eventId').val(), value);
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Try Firefox 102.0.1**

it is a stability and bug fix release. It addresses several issues that users of Firefox 102 and earlier could run into.

Also its good to go with Firefox support team
just because of this is a version related issue.
(https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1329871)